# How to disable built in keyboard in windows10 pro using code?

Tags: keyboard

What i want to happen is that, everytime i'll use my usb keyboard automatically my internal keyboard will disabale..

Chuwi brand Loptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is manually (see last paragraph). If you have coding skills, you can do these ideas, though they are ***not*** simple:

- Use an always-running Batch or PowerShell script to interface with [`devcon.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon).
- Write a driver or low-level utility to do it yourself.

If not, you should disable it manually using Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`). You'll want to check under Human Interface Devices, and disable (or enable) the keyboard that's always there.

Comment: I  have tried all possible ways.. Including what you have said except the coding ways.. But still did'nt work..

Comment: You are probably disabling the wrong device, then. I've looked at some sites and they all say that it appears as a PS/2 keyboard.
Enable any devices you disabled. Unplug *all* USB devices. Find your keyboard, disable it. Plug in the external one. Should work then.